# Cannot install Django on Windows because there is an invalid character in a filename

Tags: python, django, windows

I have been trying to *pip install django*, but I can’t do it because Windows doesn’t like the invalid filename. Do I have any options other than running a Linux virtual machine?

Comment: *"Windows doesn’t like the invalid filename"* What invalid file name? Show us the command you execute, *where* you execute it and the exact output/error you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have Git Bash installed (https://git-scm.com/download/win) and make sure python and pip are installed on your computer.

Once you have all that, just run Git Bash and execute `pip install django`. If it does not work or you have both python2 and python3 installed, use `pip3 install django`

Comment: This has nothing to do with git bash